LDA is predicting same topics for all data
I'm using the German political speech dataset to train the LDA model. My goal here is to categorize each speech into some topics. But the problem is that the generated topics are too similar, and all speech prediction is predicting the same topic.
Tried to play with parameters. I don't see any changes.
preproessing : stopword used from nltk+ some generated by GPT + some common word of topic generated by lda (try and error)
def basic_preprocess_text(text):
    # Lowercase the text
    text = text.lower()

    # Replace umlauts and ß
    text = text.replace('ä', 'ae').replace('ö', 'oe').replace('ü', 'ue').replace('ß', 'ss')

    return text

stopwords = set(basic_preprocess_text(word) for word in stopwords)

def regex_filter(text) :
      # Remove everything before ":" if the pattern matches
    text = re.sub(r'.*\[.*\]:\s*', '', text)

    # Replacing poilitical term F.D.P as FDP
    text = re.sub(r'\b([A-Z]{1})\.?([A-Z]{1})\.?([A-Z]{1})\b', r'\1\2\3', text)

    # replace occurrences of "Nordrhein Westfalen" with "NRW"
    # text = re.sub(r'nordrhein[- .]?westfalen', 'NRW', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r'nordrhein[- .]?westfalen', '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    #removing special charater
    text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Zäöüß]', ' ', text)

    return text

# Preprocessing function
def preprocess_text(text):

    text = regex_filter(text)

    # Tokenize the text
    tokens = word_tokenize(text, language='german')

    # Lemmatize the text & Basic preprocessing
    doc = nlp(' '.join(tokens))
    lemmatized_token = [basic_preprocess_text(token.lemma_) for token in doc if len(token.lemma_) > 2]

    # Remove stopwords
    lemmatized_text = ' '.join([word for word in lemmatized_token if word not in stopwords])

    return lemmatized_text
    #return tokens

Ngram :
# Ensure 'Preprocessed_Speech' is treated as a list of tokens
df['Preprocessed_tokens'] = df['Preprocessed_Speech'].apply(lambda x: x.split())


# Create bigrams and trigrams
bigram = Phrases(df['Preprocessed_tokens'], min_count=3, threshold=5)
trigram = Phrases(bigram[df['Preprocessed_tokens']], min_count=3, threshold=5)

bigram_mod = Phraser(bigram)
trigram_mod = Phraser(trigram)

# Form Bigrams and Trigrams
texts = [trigram_mod[bigram_mod[text]] for text in df['Preprocessed_tokens']]


TF-IDF : i have tried to weight some word manually but opted for now

# Create TF-IDF matrix
texts_joined = [' '.join(text) for text in texts]
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.50, min_df=5, ngram_range=(1, 2))
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(texts_joined)

# Convert TF-IDF matrix to a Gensim corpus
corpus = Sparse2Corpus(tfidf, documents_columns=False)

# Create the dictionary
id2word = {v: k for k, v in tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()}


LDA train :

# Apply LDA with adjusted parameters
num_topics = 50  # Adjust number of topics for faster experimentation
passes = 20  # Increase number of passes
iterations = 1000  # Adjust number of iterations per pass
alpha = 'auto'  # Let gensim determine the optimal alpha
eta = 'auto'  # Let gensim determine the optimal eta

lda_model = models.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=id2word, passes=passes, iterations=iterations, alpha=alpha, eta=eta)

is there something I'm doing wrong? Or Is the dataset is not suitable for this model?
